# Writing a Firefox addon to open links on a page

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

My goal is to have a button in Firefox that can open all links on a page after some filtering. However I'm running into trouble getting my addon to see the document properties. Right now I just want to be able to see the number of links on the page.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "LinkOpener",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Opens all available links",

  "icons": {
    "48": "logo48.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["LinkOpener.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "logo16.png",
      "32": "logo32.png"
    }
  }

}
```

LinkOpener.js:

```
function openPage() {
  var links = document.links;
  console.log(links.length)
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openPage);
```

When I run this and click the addon button, the console reports 0 links on the page. When I go to the console and type in `document.links.length`,  it reports 164. I'm guessing that for some reason the addon js doesn't see the page I currently have open, but I'm not sure why not.

I am aware that there are addons that can already achieve this functionality, but this is my first addon and I am using this to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the background page which belongs to the addon.

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["LinkOpener.js"]
  },
```

You need to inject the code into the page using

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://........whatever...."],
      "js": ["LinkOpener.js"]
    },
```

Comment: This was the root of my problem, thanks. Now just to figure out how to get the content scripts to communicate with the background scripts.